# Identifying bugs using Selenium IDE

Tags: eclipse, selenium, ide

First to automate an website, we'll do smoke testing, later for the same testcase we automate, so in this process recording and playbacking works well then test case is passed, but sometimes in SeleniumIDE there will be some errors like Popup window closed, iframe closed,waitforpageload functions doesn't work well.

Is that Selenium IDE problem or Website problem, then do we need to raise them as bugs?

Please answer, as I'm newbie to this selenium.

Comment: Depends on the web application. If it's a modern website, where things are AJAX'ified and some things on the page are loaded asynchronously then they are not bugs but merely the boundary of the IDE. As the answers below point out, the IDE simply isn't equipped for a *solid* testing suite.

Answer (score 0):

Those errors are not bugs - it's just that the Selenium plug-in is not intended for serious scripting, it's intended to give you some starter code. To move forward you need to familiarize yourself with Selenium webdriver and inspect the code of the web page.